# Как узнать внешний IP адрес с помощью PHP?

Tags: php

Как узнать внешний IP адрес с помощью PHP?

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` показывает 127.0.0.1

Кто может подсказать решение?

Comment: Вообще эти данные передаются по цепочке между прокси/веб-северами. Настроить веб-сервер не вариант? например, в nginx это задается как

   fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;

Comment: я так понимаю, что и сервер, и клиент у Вас локальный? В этом случае внешний айпи не имеет значение.

Comment: Сервер у меня смотрит в Интернет и есть статический внешний IP адрес...

Comment: @eprivalov1, а запрос то из интернета приходит или из локальной сети? если из локальной сети, то в PHP не будет данных о другом сетевом интерфейсе, и чтобы узнать эту инфомрацию, придется выполнить из PHP запрос к какому-то удаленному серверу, который вам вернет ваш внешний IP

Comment: Заголовок X-Forwarded-For присутствует?

Comment: @vanchester А как можно реализовать такой запрос к удаленному серверу средствами ПХП? Или лучше парсить IP адрес с такого сайта как http://2ip.ru/?

Comment: @eprivalov1, если подходить максимально просто, при наличии своего сервера в интернете с веб-севрером и php, положите туда файлик test.php с содержимым

    <?php
        echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

он будет возвращать IP, с которого на него был выполнен запрос.

а из скрипта, где нужен этот внешний адрес, просто выполняем запрос и получаем данные в переменную, опять же, в самом простом случае это можно сделать так:

    $myRemoteIp = file_get_contents('http://your-remote-server.com/test.php');

но для запросов лучше использовать функции curl_*, там возможности шире (таймаут, статус и т.п.

Comment: ну так зайдите на свой php файл с устройства с другим IP

Answer (score 2):

С помощью https://www.ipify.org/

```
<?php
$ip = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org');
echo "My public IP address is: " . $ip;
?>
```