# Есть ли в PHP директивы условной обработки скрипта?

Tags: php, условия, обработка, транслятор

В процессе моего изучения PHP столкнулся с необходимостью **условной обработки** некоторых частей скрипта. В английском это называется *conditional compilation/translation*. Не уверен, что словосочетание "условная обработка" в русском правильно передаёт смысл. Объясню на примере.

Я упражняюсь в PHP решением простых задачек, используя домашний компьютер. На localhost, иными словами. Иногда какой-то скрипт мне хочется вывесить на production-сервер. На домашней машине движок PHP настроен таким образом, что мне показываются все возможные ошибки. По понятной причине, в продакшн-среде такого быть не должно.

> Есть ли в PHP какие-то директивы, которые указывают транслятору
>   исполнять тот или иной кусок кода в зависимости, скажем, от имени
>   хоста?

То есть в скрипте должно быть прописано буквально следующее:

```
//#ЕСЛИ среда разработки/имя хоста/пр., то

  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

//#ИНАЧЕ)
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
  error_reporting(0);

//#КОНЕЦ_ЕСЛИ
```

Разумеется, перед копированием скрипта на продакшн-сервер, не должно быть необходимости вносить в него изменения.

Comment: условная "обработка" как вы говорите, это обычные if-ы. Условная же компиляция вообще исключает участки кода из исполняемого файла, тут же код остается, а просто в итоге никогда не исполняется.

Comment: А вводить в своих проектах `define('DEV', true);` и выводить только в условии если режим дев включен? Это мой метод, вам я его не навязываю, просто на серве файл настроек его задаёт от IP(у меня статика)

Comment: А вообще можете проверять внешний IP на примере этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/304759/Как-узнать-внешний-ip-адрес-с-помощью-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я смотрел на значение переменной `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']` или любой другой параметр из массива `$_SERVER`, по которому вы сможете отличить одну систему от другой

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN'] === 'admin@your-domain.com') {
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
} else {
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
  error_reporting(0);
}
```

---

А если у вас есть возможность вынести все настройки в отдельный файл, то можно просто завести два файла. Один на сервере

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
```

второй на локалхосте

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

и подключать его через `require_once`. И этот конкретный файл на сервере не заменять.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что этот блок можно просто вставить в include-файл c выражением `require_once`? Если это так, и кусок кода исполнится всего один раз, то, похоже, это ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: Именно так. А если у вас есть возможность вынести все настройки в отдельный файл, то можно просто завести два файла. Один на сервере, второй на локалхосте

Comment: Похоже, на Windows значение `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']` не инициализируется. Выдержка из документации: _Эта переменная получает свое значение (для Apache) из директивы конфигурационного файла сервера._

Comment: Но идея мне понятна. Я распечатал `print_r($_SERVER);` и выберу оттуда что-нибудь уникальное для обоих хостов.

Comment: Ну. Так в чем проблема задать ее у себя в конфиге?

Comment: Пока не знаю как )) Или переменную $_SERVER можно модифицировать?

Comment: Если у вас апач, то в файле `Apache\conf\httpd.conf` модифицируете параметр `ServerAdmin` и переапускаете сервер

Comment: В Windows (IIS) уникальным значением является индекс `$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]`. Я его и буду использовать. Большое спасибо. Принимаю ваш ответ.